# Which location to install boot-loader?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I want to dual Boot a Lenovo Flex 5 (Model 1570) Windows 10. When Ubuntu asks

```
Device for Boot loader installation
```

am I supposed to choose `/dev/sda` as below?
[image: Ubuntu Partitions]

Just trying to confirm, I don't want to wipe my Windows partitions: 
[image: Windows Partitions]

Comment: Your Windows OS disk is factory-configured with a dynamic overlay that Ubuntu cannot read or understand. Back off. Any workaround or try to install will kill your Windows OS disk. Please use Virtualbox instead.

Comment: So VirtualBox is the only solution? I can't dual boot any other Linux distro?

Comment: Yes, unless you ditch Windows OS, paid license, and recovery partition! (i.e. repartition)

Comment: That is super depressing to hear. So not even RedHat Enterprise Linux? You've technically answered this, just really wanted a Linux distro.

Comment: The problem is not "Linux"; not even "Windows": It is *dynamic-overlay*. The problem is your disk.

Comment: You might be able to figure this out further if I tell you that even a Windows Server will have trouble dual-booting on your disk!

Comment: Would you be kind enough to list some sources I could read about dynamic-overlay? Not really understanding. Regardless, thank you a lot. I appreciate your honesty.

Comment: Sure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_drive_overlay

Comment: Also, in this case, a Flex 5 is basically worthless then if I want to run Linux. Would you recommend getting a Mac, or an older Windows laptop (any recommendations)? Again, can't thank you enough, I've been struggling on this for 2 straight weeks

Comment: Please note however that the wiki definition is the original purpose of DDO. In your case, like many others, it used to facilitate automated recovery on pre-loaded PCs/Laptops (because it allows tweaking and resizing partitions on the fly without 3rd party software that Lenovo and others do not want to pay for)

Comment: I would suggest any brand or any model that does not come pre-loaded with software; not even a Linux OS. Try models that come with FreeDOS; those you can clean, reformat/repartition as you need.

Comment: @MK: OP is better off downloading a Windows 10 ISO from the Microsoft Website, all the drivers he needs from the Lenovo web site, wipe everything using the Ubuntu USB stick; install Windows correctly and then installing Ubuntu...  Do you want to post that as an answer or shall I as I agree his disk overlay is the root cause of the problem...µ

Comment: @Fabby so basically you recommend installing Ubuntu first (erasing everything), then installing Windows?

Comment: Nope: use Ubuntu to wipe everything using the "try Ubuntu" option but don't install, then Install Windows, then Install Ubuntu, but let's wait until @MK reports back...

Comment: possible to dual-boot Ubuntu with this tutorial even? https://medium.com/@petragospodneti/windows-10-and-linux-love-hate-dual-boot-problems-d9994cbe16c0

Comment: @Fabby I did not want to post my comment as answer, because it does not actually "solve" the problem of proceeding with installation. As for wiping off and starting clean, I did not want to advise with that either, because in my experience: 1) some OEMs do not provide actual Windows activation key with pre-loaded device, so this would mean loss of paid license 2) although rare, some users like and want to keep the automated recovery option of the OEM, along with OEM own add-ons that might not be available to download separately.

Comment: @Fabby If Windows activation key is available, and OP does not care about OEM automated recovery, then I would heartily go with clean install, but in my opinion it would only need disk wipe then a Windows install with BIOS set to UEFI disabled (better for dual booting), then Ubuntu install selecting the legacy non-UEFI installer option.

Comment: **@MK** Yeah, this is going to be too complex for a simple Q & Answer site as deploying Ubuntu on a machine like that will have to be broken into multiple questions. I think we have an answer for the original question though and that is: No, you should not do that.  Will you answer that or shall I? **adam_smith**: Ask Ubuntu is not a consultancy site, but a simple Q&A site: One question one answer.  This is turning into "How do I have to dual boot with my specific hardware? (which I don't have and I'd be surprised if MK does as well)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu CAN be dual-booted on the Flex 5 (without wiping Windows). All you have to do is change the controller type from Intel RST Premium to AHCI. I was wary of doing this because of the scary warnings Windows was giving me about "breaking my existing partitions".

You must change this setting in safe mode (otherwise Windows will fail to boot!), from Intel RST Premium to AHCI [3]. This is because safe mode "avoid[s] loading conflicting drivers" [2].

Steps to dual boot:

1. While creating a USB live disk for Ubuntu using Rufus, select GPT partition scheme for UEFI [1].
2. In BIOS settings, set Boot to UEFI before running installation for Ubuntu
3. Follow instructions in article to change from RST Premium to AHCI: https://medium.com/@petragospodneti/windows-10-and-linux-love-hate-dual-boot-problems-d9994cbe16c0
4. Boot with USB and install Ubuntu normally. In my experience, I knew it worked because it gave me a "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows" option, previously not available.

References:

[1] https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Flex-5-Linux-Support/td-p/3704110

[2] https://superuser.com/questions/1251596/why-safe-mode-when-changing-from-ide-to-ahci

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Host_Controller_Interface

Extra reading: https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/44694.html